# Bash exec in infinite while loop doesn't work

Tags: bash, while-loop, exec, infinite-loop

```
#!/bin/bash 
while :
do
    echo twerkin
    exec free -h > /ver/www/raspberry/load.txt
    exec /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp > /var/www/raspberry/heat.txt
done
```

This is what I made, I am going to read it on my website, but thats not the problem. The problem is that it gives me this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sh showinfo.sh
showinfo.sh: 7: showinfo.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting "do")
```

I'm running this on my raspberry pi with Raspbian (Debian Wheezy)

Comment: Please add the error to the question

Comment: Added error, (it was in the image previously)

Comment: Running a Bash script with `sh` is always an error.  But your script works fine here (apart from the obvious misunderstanding of what `exec` does) without errors.

Comment: Why is it not working over here than? Is it because of the stripped out version of Debian Wheezy??? (Raspbian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't seem to understand what the `exec` keyword does.  It **replaces** your current script (basically, the`while` loop) with the `free` command.

To run a command, simply specify it.

```
#!/bin/bash

while : ; do
    free -h
    /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp 
done
```

(I omitted the redirections because you were overwriting the old results on each iteration. What do you actually want?)

Comment: How can I let bash run another program than?

Comment: I want output from every thing I run in 2 seperate files, so free- h in /var/www/raspberry/load.txt and the output from /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp in /var/www/raspberry/heat.txt, so that I can read them with HTML.

Comment: They are not HTML.  If you want to append to the file on each iteration, use `>>`.

Answer (score 0):

try to change few things in your script

```
#!/bin/bash 

while : ;
do
    echo twerkin

    #### commands to execute are not need to be prefixed with exec
    #### + concatenate output with >>
    free -h >> /ver/www/raspberry/load.txt

    #### same here
    /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp >> /var/www/raspberry/heat.txt

    #### you probably would want to add a delay here, because in other way
    #### the script will be executed probably way too fast
    # sleep 0.01

done
```

Comment: Thanks for you input! But it gives this error:
pi@raspberry ~ $ ./showinfo.sh
: no such file or directory

Comment: I found another way to do it without the loop, I don't know why it doesn't work. Has it anything to do with SSH?